# How to get the height of an image and apply that height to a div?

Tags: css, jquery, mobile

I am building a mobile web app and I'm using jquerytools slider on it.

i want te slider to show (in proper ratio) across all mobile devices so width of the images is 100% and height is auto in css. However as all the elements are floated and jquerytools slider requires the position be set to absolute, the containing div (#header) doesn't stretch to fit the content.

I am trying to use jquery to get the height of the height of the img and apply that height to the header.... however I am having no luck.

CSS:

```
    #header{
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index: 20;
/* box-shadow: 0 0 10px white; */
overflow: auto;
}

.scrollable {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/* box-shadow: 0 0 20px purple; */
/*  height:198px; */
z-index: 20;
overflow: auto;
}


.scrollable .items {
/* this cannot be too large */
width:1000%;
position:absolute;
clear:both;
/* box-shadow: 0 0 30px green; */

}

.items div {
float:left;
width:10%;
height:100%;

}

/* single scrollable item */
.scrollable img {
    /* float:left; */
    width:100%;
   height: auto;
 /*    height:198px; */
}

/* active item */
.scrollable .active {
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id=header><!-- root element for scrollable -->
    <div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">

      <!-- root element for the items -->
      <div class="items">


        <div>
          <img src="img/img2.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div>
           <img src="img/img1.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div>
         <img src="img/img3.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div>
         <img src="img/img4.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div>
         <img src="img/img6.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div><!-- items -->

    </div><!-- scrollable -->

    </div><!-- header -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The code supplied by Sdespont was perfect and it guided me to the answer. The reason his code was showing zero for height was because it was looking for the image height, before the images had loaded. To remedy this i changed

```
$(document).ready
```

to

```
$(window).load
```

solved. Thanks to @sdespont

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var height = $('#myImageID').height();
$('#header').height(height);
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: tried this but didnt work.<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var height = $('img.scrollable').height();
  $('#header').height(height);
  });
  </script>

Comment: Your selector $('img.scrollable').height(); is false. Add id to your image and use it as selector to retrieve its height like $('#myimg1').height();

Comment: Or retrieve only by class like $('.scrollable').height();

Comment: so infuriating. both your suggestions seem like total common sense, but still no joy. script below:

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
             var height = $('#imgheight').height();
  $('#header').height(height);
  });
  </script>

Comment: what do you get with debugger F12? or console.log(height)? If you don't get value, your selector is false, else you could also try to apply using $('#header').css('height',height+'px');

Comment: I am outputting the height variable to the screen and it is showing as 0. I have definitely given the image an id tag of imgheight, it is showing up in chromes developer tools as being 891px tall.....

Comment: Perhaps a browser issue. What is your JQuery version? Try to retrieve the height through $('#imgheight').css('height')

Comment: I am using jquerytools 1.2.7 full. It's really odd and btw I really appreciate your help. It's a mobile site but if you want to look at it in browser its www.wearelogan.com